# Como obter a data e hora da máquina para criar uma pasta?

Tags: c#

Olá!
Qual a melhor forma para obter a data e hora da máquina usando C# e criar uma pasta com o formato 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS' garantindo que nunca tenha duas pastas com o mesmo nome?

Comment: Qual o objetivo? Você quer criemos para você uma ferramenta de linha de comando tipo `md` só que com data e hora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta utilizar esse exemplo abaixo, você deve alterar o path!

```
DateTime dta = DateTime.Now; 
string dtaStr = dta.ToString("dd" + "-" + "MM" + "-" + "yyyy" + " " + "HH" + "-" + "mm"); //data formatada to string
string subPath ="/path/"+dtaStr; // Seu codigo com a data e hora vai aqui

bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath)); // verifica se a pasta ja existe

if(!exists)
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath)); //se não existir ele cria
```